# How do I update a variable outside an AJAX session? (Backbone JS / CoffeeScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript

For example, I want to update my_data with the session results:

```
    my_data = []
    url = "/some/endpoint/"

    Session.ajax
        url: url
        type: 'get'
        success: (data) ->
          my_data = data

    console.log JSON.stringify(my_data)
    return my_data
```

my_data is still empty, so this is definitely not working. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the correct way.

`my_data` is empty because you log it before the request has completed (it is done asynchronously after all).

You can log (or otherwise use) it inside the `success` callback.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it inside the success callback, that works, however I would like to return the data outside of/after the session. Is that possible?

edit// taking a look at the attached duplicated now.